# AngularJS having Trouble in $http feedback to user in template

Tags: angularjs

My snippet is working well for now. it works like if a user submit something error, he gets an error message, if he successfully submit, he gets a success message, it works nice, no issue with that.

at first see my current snippet:

```
$scope.onSubmit = function () {
      $http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/contact', $scope.formModel)
      .then(function(response) {
        $scope.saveSuccess = true;
        $scope.message = 'You have successfully saved your contact';
        $scope.contacts.push(response.data);
      }, function(response) {
        $scope.saveSuccess = false;
        $scope.message = 'an error occurs';
      });
  };
```

and here you go to see how i used this on template:
Note: the css is bootstrap clss.

```
<div class="alert" ng-class="{ 'alert-success': saveSuccess, 'alert-danger': !saveSuccess }">
          <p> {{ message }} </p>
</div> 

My problem is, when i visit the page, it always shows me an danger color with no message
```

but it works nice when a user submit error, they get error message with danger color and if he successfully post, he gets success message with succcess color

**Only problem is, if an error occurs or not, a success occurs or not, it always shows a danger color with no text by default, why? but when error occurs or success occurs, it works nice its way.**

I hope you got my issue.

here you go for screenshot: [image]

this is always exist but if error occurs, it works nice, here you go to see the 2nd screenshot:

[image]

I have problem with first screenshot i provided and i am not getting why its happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you boolean variable initially has a value of undefined, so this condition becomes true:

```
!saveSuccess
```

you will need another boolean to set when the form is submitted (added in finally block, which fires in both cases success/error):

```
$scope.onSubmit = function () {
  $http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/contact', $scope.formModel)
  .then(function(response) {
    $scope.saveSuccess = true;
    $scope.message = 'You have successfully saved your contact';
    $scope.contacts.push(response.data);
  }, function(response) {
    $scope.saveSuccess = false;
    $scope.message = 'an error occurs';
  }).finally(function() {
    $scope.submitted = true;
});
```

};

and add it in template in ng-if condition:

```
 <div ng-if="submitted" class="alert" ng-class="{ 'alert-success': saveSuccess, 'alert-danger': 
 !saveSuccess }">
          <p> {{ message }} </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, You have made my day, much appreciated